# How to use the recent documents folder in VLC Player

Tags: windows-7, windows, vlc-media-player

Using Windows 7, how can I open the recent documents folder in VLC Player?

Answer (score 2):

First you have to unhide the hidden files/folders because the recent-folder is hidden.

**Unhide**

1. Open Folder Options by clicking the Start button, clicking Control Panel, clicking Appearance and Personalization, and then clicking Folder Options.
2. Click the View tab.
3. Under Advanced settings, click Show hidden files, folders, and drives, and then click OK.

**Folder-Location**

The path is:
`C:\Users\yourusername\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent`

[image]

**Open Folder in vlc:**

1. Click on File --> Open Folder.
2. Navigate to the path, which now should be visible.
3. Open the Folder you want.